# hello.jsp file is not running on tomcat8.0

Tags: jsp, tomcat8

**i created a file  hello.jsp
in the folder
c:\Apache-Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT
the file is given below :**

```
    < html>    
          <head>
               <title>Hello World</title>    
          </head>      
      <body> 
             Hello World
            !<br/>
          <% out.println("Your IP address is " + request.getRemoteAddr());%>                                               
      </body> 
   </html>
```

---

**i tried to run in the localhost server through the following URL:
http://localhost:8080/hello.jsp
but i am getting the following error :**

> Apache tatus 404 - /hello.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /hello.jsp
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.21

*

---

how to run the above hello.jsp file please help me

*

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse EE for Deploy a project to localhost:8080. [Dowload Eclipse Here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunasr2).

1. Create New Dynamic Web Project.
2. Select your server in options.
3. In your project->WEB-INF create hello.jsp.
4. Right click to hello.jsp->Run on server
5. You can see your page at : http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/hello.jsp